# Grab everything after value in variable

Tags: php

In `$contents`, I'd like to grab everything after the pipe e.g. `boss`.

```
$search_for = "micky.mcgurk";
$contents = "micky.mcgurk@somewebsite.com|boss";
$pattern = sprintf('/\b%s@([^|\s]+)\|/m', preg_quote($search_for));

if (preg_match_all($pattern, $contents, $matches)) {
    $submitted_by = implode("\n", $matches[1]);
} else {
   echo "No user found";
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It returns `somewebsite.com`

Comment: I think I just need a Regex pattern to grab anything **after** the pipe.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$resultat = substr(strrchr($content, '|'), 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use explode?

```
$contents = "micky.mcgurk@somewebsite.com|boss";
$result = explode("|", $contents);
echo $result[1];
```

This requires, that mail address and the content after "|" is not having a "|" also ... ;)

Answer (score 1):

RegExp way:

```
$pipe = preg_quote('|', '/');
$regExp = '/.*' . $pipe . '(.*)$/';
```

The fastest way:

```
$name = substr($string, strpos($string, '|') + 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer about what's happening with your current regex:

```
([^|\s]+)
```

matches every continuous non `|` and whitespace character. Once it encounters that it stops. Because of the capture groups `()` that is captured.

https://regex101.com/r/DVY3F0/2/

What you want is directly after that though. If you add:

```
\|\K.*
```

and remove that previous capture group you will have you want at the `0` index.

https://regex101.com/r/DVY3F0/3/

In full form:

```
\bmicky\.mcgurk@[^|\s]+\|\K.*
```

or you could just have it as a vague check for non `|` until a `|`.

```
[^|]+?\|\K.*
```

https://regex101.com/r/yvzdDu/1/